# Not able to click on POST button with xpath code

Tags: post, xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember558\"]")).click();
```

I am doing testing for linkedin post. I entered this code for POST button but that does not work. Can you please suggest about this?

Comment: Make sure that `@id` value is not dynamic then try Implicit/Explicit wait

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @id attribute value is dynamic so, it will not be able to interact with the Element. You can try with dynamic X-path techniques. Generally, a set of data keeps on changing and rest data remains same.

e.g. <button "id":"emns1233">
here starting part of id will remain same every time but last part that is 1233 will change (may be each time). So, one can try to write X-path as

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@id,'emn')])).

Hope it helps. Thanks